# How to split audio encoding across multiple application launches?

Tags: ios, audio, encoding, m4a

My app needs to encode a large amount of audio data to an M4A file. I am currently using AVAssetWriter, which works fine, except that it takes a few minutes to encode all the data. 
Instead of asking the user to keep the app running until the process has finished, I would like to pause the encoding when the app terminates and continue on relaunch.
Unfortunately, AVAssetWriter doesn't seem to support this, as it always creates a new file when initializing.
Do you know any other APIs that I could use? Maybe a third-party library?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what background processing is intended for. As long as you can complete within 10 minutes, you can use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` to ask the system to let you keep running after the user switches applications. See [Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) in the iOS Application Programming Guide. Not only is this the easiest to use, but it'll give the best user experience.

The only issue you'd face is if it's possible for an audio file to take longer than 10 minutes in a non-resumable way. If that's a real possibility, then you'll need another solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The amount of data to be encoded is defined by the user, so I would prefer a solution without such a time limit.
I'm also not sure about how hardware-assisted encoding affects audio playback of other apps while my app is running in the background.